# Display shifted to left (Wayland)

Tags: display, display-resolution, wayland

I was having a problem with the resolution of my display on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I used 1280x1024 on Windows, But it was not available in the resolution drop down in the display settings. I managed to fix it by adding/EDITING this line as follows:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=VGA-1:1280x1024@60"`

This fixed my resolution issue. However, now my display is shifted towards left (an inch or half). I tried lowering the resolution and reverting it back again, and It actually fixed the problem for a moment. But when I restarted the system the problem was still there (The resolution was again shifted to left). I again fixed the problem by lowering the resolution and reverting it. But whenever I restart, the resolution is disturbed again...

I have to constantly do this fix whenever I start my system. Is there a permanent fix to this?